# Finding the number of connected components in an undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph

**Source:**

[here](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/)

**Problem:**

> Given n nodes labeled from 0 to n - 1 and a list of undirected edges (each edge is a pair of nodes), write a function to find the number of connected components in an undirected graph.

**Approach:**

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    int countComponents(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges) 
    {
        std::vector<bool> v(n, false);
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if(!v[i])
            {
                dfs(edges, v, i);
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    void dfs(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& edges, std::vector<bool>& v, int i)
    {
        if(v[i] || i > edges.size())
            return;

        v[i] = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < edges[i].size(); ++j)
            dfs(edges, v, edges[i][j]);
    }
};
```

**Error:**

heap-buffer overflow

I am not understanding why my code is causing a heap-buffer overflow for the test case:

```
5
[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my code would be really appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, but it is strange that you compare `i`, which appears to be an index into *vertices* against the size of a vector of *edges.*

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your `edges` vector has only four elements in it for the provided input, since there is no outgoing edge from vertex 4. Your `dfs` function then eventually recurs into the point where i == 4, but your `edges` vector has only 4 elements, thus the last valid possition is `edges[3]`.

I suggest that you represent a vertex with no outgoing vertices with an empty vector.

Also, the second part of the if statement

```
if(v[i] || i > edges.size())
        return;
```

seems unecceserry and should probably just be

```
if(v[i])
        return;
```